# Secondary unique field split by data access group in REDCap

Tags: redcap

I am doing a multi-center study where we want to ensure that a secondary field, `hospital_number`, beyond the standard assigned `record_id`, is a unique identifier. However, because multiple centers could have the same number, we want to split the uniqueness of this secondary field based on which data access group the record belongs to. Don't think that there is any way of doing this in REDCap through the "Secondary Unique Field" function in the study setup.

An attempt I've made is to make a `dag_hospital_number` field that is computed through `@CALCTEXT([user-dag-id],'-',[hospital_number])`. However, when you set this field as a "Secondary Unique Field", and then trial it by adding a duplicate field, you get stuck--because the `dag_hospital_number` is a calculated field, the user-interface trips out because you aren't able to immediately change secondary unique field. Essentially, this [popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zwry.png) keeps popping up no matter what you do.

My only other idea is to try to set up a warning field based on branching logic on if the `dag_hospital_number` is duplicated, and abandon the "Secondary Unique Field" thing altogether. Is there any way for branching logic/piping to consider previously entered records? It seems like the only things you can use for branching logic/piping are values from that same record, from what I've read. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an interesting scenario, and I don't know the answer.  Most institutions prefer to have their REDCap admins answer these questions. Were you able to reach one of them?  If they don't know the answer, consider asking them to post a question on the private forums available to REDCap admins.